# Создать таблицу из нескольких списков

Tags: c#, коллекции, логика, syncfusion, wasm

Сергей может видеть работы нескольких гаражей, вначале он идентифицируется, ему выходит лист ВСЕХ гаражей ему доступных, затем Сергей выбирает из списка гаражи, которые ему нужны прямо сейчас, все это происходит на странице1 для выбора в списке я использую Syncfusion

```
<SfMultiSelect TValue="string[]" TItem="GarajModel" Placeholder=@myLocalizerTrad["ChoiceGaraj"] DataSource="@garajsList" @bind-Value="@MultiVal" Mode="VisualMode.Box">
    <MultiSelectFieldSettings Text="NameGaraje" Value="CodeGaraj" />
    <MultiSelectEvents TItem="GarajModel" TValue="string[]" OnValueSelect="OnSelect" OnValueRemove="OnDeselect" ValueChange="@OnSelectValue" />
</SfMultiSelect>
```

класс Модель

```
public class GarajModel
{
    public string NameGaraje {get; set;}
    public string CodeGaraj {get; set;}
}
```

когда Сергей выбирает из списка гараж1 и гараж2 он "идентифитируется" второй раз и переходит на страницу2 где таблица показывает ему "работы" тех гаражей что он выбрал.

таблица на второй странице

```
<SfGrid @ref="Grid" DataSource="@tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza" Height="auto">
    </GridFilterSettings>

    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn ......
       
        </GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>
```

передаю данные этой таблице через событие

```
IEnumerable<ModelRabotiGaraja> tablicaVremennaya;
IEnumerable<ModelRabotiGaraja> tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza;


private async Task GetRabotiGarajey()
{
    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = null; //иначе прибавляет потом строки
    tablicaVremennaya = null; //то же самое

    foreach (var garaje in SpisokGarajey)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code2))
            try
            {
                tablicaVremennaya = await garajService.GetGarajList(garaj.code1, garaj.code2);

                if (tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza == null)
                {
                    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = missionListsModelTemp.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = 
                tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza.Concat(tablicaVremennaya); 
//то есть первый гараж в таблице уже есть и я добавляю строки второго гаража с помощью Concat                                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string msg = e.Message;
            }
    }

    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

**КАК НАПИСАТЬ ГРАММОТНО ДАННЫЙ КОД**

*(подправить логику события `GetRabotiGarajey`)*, чтоб в дальнейшем не думать о нагрузке программы и возможных оплошностях ?

***хотелось бы получить ответа пожалуйста обратите внимание на этот вопрос

Comment: Чет странное вы делаете. Обычно данные хранятся в базе, и мы просто достаем их так: `var items = db.Table.Where(x=>x.Type == ItemType.Open);`, условие естественно разное, под разные задачи. А вы непойми что делаете, крутите циклы, чет достаете, постоянно работаете с полным набором данных, и т.д. Если топорно ответить на ваш вопрос, то `foreach (var item in await garajService.GetGarajList(...)){ tablicaVremennaya.Add(item); }` или `tablicaVremennaya.AddRange(await garajService.GetGarajList(...))` (может потребоваться `.ToArray()`).

Comment: `List<RabotiGaraja>? tablicaVremennaya;`. И далее делаете `tablicaVremennaya.Add`.

Comment: пользователь подключается и у него выбор гаражей (не у всех пользователей одинаковый доступ). Потом из списка он выбирает по параметрам гаражи, и потом по гаражам я показываю какие работы он может видеть в этом/этих гаражей.

Answer (score 1):

я использовала `Concat`  и немного изменила метод, в итоге моя таблица показывает верные данные.

```
IEnumerable<ModelRabotiGaraja> tablicaVremennaya;
IEnumerable<ModelRabotiGaraja> tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza;


private async Task GetRabotiGarajey()
{
    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = null; //иначе прибавляет потом строки
    tablicaVremennaya = null; //то же самое

    foreach (var garaje in SpisokGarajey)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code2))
            try
            {
                tablicaVremennaya = await garajService.GetGarajList(garaj.code1, garaj.code2);

                if (tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza == null)
                {
                    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = missionListsModelTemp.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = 
                tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza.Concat(tablicaVremennaya); 
//то есть первый гараж в таблице уже есть и я добавляю строки второго гаража с помощью Concat                                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string msg = e.Message;
            }
    }

    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы правильно получить для пользователя все списки гаражей нужно использовать массив или коллекцию.
До цикла вы указали  **tablicaVremennaya = null;** а в самом цикле **tablicaVremennaya = awaitgarajService.GetGarajList(garaj.code1, garaj.code2);** то есть каждый проход цикла создает новый гараж. Используйте к примеру

```
     // Создаем коллекцию гаражей
var GarageTemp = new List<tablicaVremennaya>();
private async Task GetRabotiGarajey()
{   
    foreach (var garaj in SpisokGarajey)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code2))
                GarageTemp.Add(await garajService.GetGarajList(garaj.code1, garaj.code2)); 
    }
    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = tablicaVremennaya;
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

В  вашем ответе все работает за счёт условий, при втором проходе цикла все также создается таблица tablicaVremennaya, то есть в каждом новом повторении перезаписывается в памяти таблица и за счёт условий if else вы склеиваете данные, обращение к ним и их свойствам в этом случае не очень удобное так как по id будет не так просто получить то что надо, вам выдаст все два класса. Посмотрите мой пример. Если у вас разные таблицы tablicaVremennaya и tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza. Вы можете создать промежуточную таблицу. И загружать данные в нее. И будет доступ к обоим классам без костылей

Comment: спасибо за Ваш отзыв, я подправила свой ответ, и если вы заметите,  я использую одну и ту же модель для моих таблиц, вы же использовали в качестве модели временную таблицу, пока что не понимаю как изменить мой код

Comment: @Dev18 сильных отличий не вижу, модели данных по прежнему работают за счет  условий, у вас 2 представления гаража, но представьте если бы их было 1000, писать условия чтобы не перезаписывались данные с каждым проходом цикла и писать Contact везде... И + не удобная обработка данных. Изучите мой пример в нем вы можете создать и 1000 гаражей и доступ будет к каждому из них удобный. Я не использовал в Примере временную таблицу, я создал коллекцию моделей гаражей

Comment: Советую изучить как работать с коллекциями и моделями данных https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.5.php

Comment: ```tablicaVremennaya``` ведь изначально пустая, и вообще инициализируется только в этом цикле, а иначе, когда пользователь меняет страницы, или заходит второй раз логинится, то таблица прибавляет и прибавляет данные. поэтому и даю ровно нуль, чтобы стереть данные, а как подать что то что не инитицализированно в качестве типа моей коллекции, будь то список или Iennumerable. Я почитала про списки, но пока не понимаю как изменить в моем случае. 

Comment: @Dev18 смотрите суть модели данных идет в том что вы создаете класс со всеми полями и далее это удобно использовать. Будь это одна модель, да не нужно было их разделять. Но у вас одна модель и два раза используете, вам лучше использовать коллекцию для разделения данных, а далее вы можете сортировать их как вам угодно. И вы пишете при повторном обращение к модели вы ее перезаписываете, этого не нужно делать. Достаточно получить модель из коллекции и изменить нужные поля, сохраняя целостность данных

Comment: Вот еще пример работы с моделями http://dir.by/developer/csharp/list/find/