# компонент Syncfusion дает исключение Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion

Я использую syncfusion в моем приложении blazor web assembly

```
<SfGrid @ref="Grid" DataSource="@IEnumerable<MissionListModel> garajModel;" Height="550" AllowReordering="true" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">
    <GridEvents TValue="MissionListModel" RowDataBound="RowBound"></GridEvents>           
    <GridPageSettings PageSize="15"></GridPageSettings>
    <GridFilterSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.CheckBox" Mode="FilterBarMode.Immediate" ImmediateModeDelay="300"></GridFilterSettings> 

        <GridColumns>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(GarajListModel.champs1) HeaderText="champs1" Width="120" Type=ColumnType.String 
                        FilterSettings="@(new FilterSettings{ Operator = Operator.Contains })">
            </GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(GarajListModel.champs2) HeaderText="champs2" Width="100"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(GarajListModel.champs3) HeaderText="champs3" Type=ColumnType.String Width="120" DisableHtmlEncode="false"></GridColumn>       
        </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>
```

```
public void RowBound(RowDataBoundEventArgs<MissionListModel> args)
{
    if (условие)
    {
        args.Row.AddClass(new string[] { "класс css" }); //окрашиваю строку
    }
    else
    {
        if (условие)  
        {     
            окрашиваю строку в др цвет
        }
        else
        {
            args.Row.AddClass(new string[] { "transpRow" }); // на всякий случай сбрасываю цвета
        }
    }       
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

данные в таблице появляются из мульти-фильтра с другой страницы

```
<SfMultiSelect TValue="string[]" TItem="ModelGaraj" Placeholder=@myLocalizer["ViberiteGaraj(i)"] DataSource="@List<ModelGaraj> listGarajey">
    <MultiSelectFieldSettings Text="imya_garaja" Value="code_garaja" />
    <MultiSelectEvents TItem="ModelGaraj" TValue="string[]" OnValueSelect="OnSelect" />
</SfMultiSelect>
```

```
public void OnSelect(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.SelectEventArgs<ModelGaraj> args)
{
    var selectedValue = args.ItemData;

    if (selectedValue != null)
    {
        try
        {
            ObshiyListGarajeyDlyaPokaza.Add(selectedValue);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            string exMsg = Ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull(Object value, String paramName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Validate(Type type, Boolean allowByRef)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(Type type, String name)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Data.QueryableExtensions.Parameter(Type sourceType)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Data.EnumerableOperation.PerformFiltering(IEnumerable dataSource, List`1 whereFilter, String condition)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.DataOperations.PerformFiltering(IEnumerable dataSource, List`1 whereFilter, String condition)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Data.BlazorAdaptor.DataOperationInvoke[ModelRabotiGarajey](IEnumerable DataSource, DataManagerRequest queries)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Data.BlazorAdaptor.
```

это исключение, которое я получаю. какой тип `(Parameter 'type')` в данном случае имеется ввиду, я пытаюсь отлаживать чтоб просмотреть все данные, вроде все везде заполненно, только вот данное исключение бросает, когда я нажимаю на иконку поиска в компоненте синфузион.
вот что интересно, когда в мультипоиске я выбираю более одного гаража, все работает корректно, а когда один гараж, то что то работает неккоректно,

**ПОЖАЛУЙСТА помогите разобраться**

*//у меня не хватило репутации добавить метку `Syncfusion`. понятно, что у них есть свое сообщество, там я не нашла ответа и задала свой вопрос там тоже естественно, но можно добавить метку и тут, чтоб расширить вопросы и ответы для программистов в русскоязычном сообществе*

Comment: Syncfusion же платный фреймворк, быть может в поддержку им написать будет эффективнее?

Comment: да, платный. написала, но возможно разница во времени, ответа пока не поступило, но я нашла мой bug и сейчас работает корректно, просто пока не отписалась и думаю возможно изменить код по совету @Иван Рудаков в другом вопросе.,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае, [функция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504836/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85), по которой строится байндинг моей таблице, только при повторном прохождении цикла преоразовываЛА объект в лист, я пыталась разобраться в функциях, по видимому, когда мой байндинг еще не являлся листом, он воспринимал как пустое и выдавал ошибку. ниже функция  `syncfusion` для фильтра и собственно функция `concat`, благодаря которой мой объект стал листом, и пройдя много раз все варианты, я поняла, что `syncfusion`ждет лист,,, *//фильтр не выдает больше данной ошиюбки и задача решенна*

```
//fonctionne de filtre Syncfusion
//
// Résumé :
//     Processing the property value changes and invoking the events for two-way bindings.
internal virtual async Task<T> UpdateProperty<T>(string propertyName, T publicValue, T privateValue, object eventCallback = null, Expression<Func<T>> expression = null)
{
    T finalResult = publicValue;
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(publicValue, privateValue))
    {
            T newValue = (DirectParameters.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? ((T)DirectParameters[propertyName]) : publicValue);
            bool flag = eventCallback != null && ((EventCallback<T>)eventCallback).HasDelegate;
            bool isPropertyBinding = !SfBaseUtils.Equals(publicValue, newValue) && IsRerendering;
            SfBaseComponent sfBaseComponent = ((MainParent != null) ? MainParent : this);
            bool flag2 = IsRerendering && flag;
            finalResult = ((flag2 || isPropertyBinding || !sfBaseComponent.IsRendered) ? publicValue : privateValue);
            if (flag)
        {
           await ((EventCallback<T>)eventCallback).InvokeAsync(finalResult);
        }
        if (isPropertyBinding)
        {
            DirectParameters[propertyName] = finalResult;
            SfBaseUtils.UpdateDictionary(propertyName, finalResult, base.PropertyChanges);
        }
    }
     return finalResult;
}
        
        
        
//fonctionne Concat     
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    if (first == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.first);
    }

    if (second == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.second);
    }

    return first is ConcatIterator<TSource> firstConcat
        ? firstConcat.Concat(second)
        : new Concat2Iterator<TSource>(first, second);
}
```

***использовав `Concat` я получала лист, и поэтому, я добавила `missionListsModelTemp.**ToList();**` при выбрасывании исключения и это помогло.

```
private async Task GetRabotiGarajey()
{
    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = null; //иначе прибавляет потом строки
    tablicaVremennaya = null; //то же самое

    foreach (var garaje in SpisokGarajey)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(garaj.code2))
            try
            {
                tablicaVremennaya = await garajService.GetGarajList(garaj.code1, garaj.code2);

                if (tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza == null)
                {
//тут я преобразовала в лист и это помогло, но мне не ясно...
                    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza =missionListsModelTemp.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza = 
                tablicaPoKotoroyDelayuBindingPokaza.Concat(tablicaVremennaya); 
//то есть первый гараж в таблице уже есть и я добавляю строки второго гаража с помощью Concat                                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string msg = e.Message;
            }
    }

    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

**вопрос решен, но не удовлетворителен**